# how to make a browser/search engine ignore detecting current location

Tags: browser, search-engines

A lot of people are annoyed (including me) when a browser/search engine detects the regional settings. If I am in Romania, it redirect the search engine to google.ro and sets the language to RO. I know how to modify the language, and I can search using www.google.com/webhp, but I don't want to do this every day, i was hoping that there is a setting or an addon to disable the detection

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome, but also IE/FF/Opera/CoolNovo/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Chrome:

1. Click on the wrench icon (top right)
2. Click on Settings
3. Go to "Under the Hood" -> Privacy -> "Content Settings"
4. Find the "Location" section and check "Do not allow any site to track my physical location"
5. Close "Content Settings"
6. Close Settings tab

For instructions for IE9 or Firefox, go to [this site](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/149275-ie9-allow-prevent-websites-request-your-location.html)

Answer (score 10):

Visit http://www.google.com/ncr. NCR stands for "no country redirect", and visiting that link sets a cookie that will prevent redirects in the future. As long as the cookie is set, you will get the global site and results. If you want to get regional results, click on "Go to Google %country%" at the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: Wow this is the first solution that actually works!

Answer (score 0):

Just set http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=us as your home page. Or if you use Firefox goto about:config and change **keyword.URL** to http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=us#hl=en&q=

See here for more info:
[Change the default search engine for Firefox's address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/253879/change-the-default-search-engine-for-firefoxs-address-bar)