# Set Google Chrome search to ignore location

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

The default search in Chrome 18 is

`{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s`

How can I modify the search parameters to ignore the location, like in  http://www.google.com/ncr

Comment: Check the answers on [this post][1].


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/410341/how-to-make-a-browser-search-engine-ignore-detecting-current-location

Comment: have you tried that, it still redirects to google.ro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find your Chrome *User Data* directory:

- Windows XP: `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data`
- Windows 7: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`
- Mac OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
- Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome` or `~/.config/chromium`

Open the `Local State` file in a text editor, and change the `browser.last_known_google_url` value to your desired domain. For example:

```
{
    ...,
    "browser": {
        ...,
        "last_known_google_url": "http://www.google.com/",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that for Windows 8 it's not APPDATA, but _LOCALAPPDATA_ ... So when you come back here to read why you didn't find it, this is why.

Comment: Using Chrome 22 on Mac, this doesn't seem to work anymore. Still getting German results :(

Comment: I confirm it doesn't work anymore. Version 31.x on Mac. :(

Comment: This _does_ work for me today, except that the setting has moved to `~/.config/google-chrome-beta/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

Exit Chrome with Ctrl-Shift-Q.

Find the `Preferences` file in the user data directory, and change `last_known_google_url` to the desired value. Then restart it.