# Are websites ignoring locale or they are relying on IP?

Tags: locale

I’m currently in Germany wonder why so many websites ignore my locale settings (in OS and browser) and are instead showing me content in German? Is it possible to turn this off? My locale is `en-US`.

Example:

- Open browser
- `google.com` => <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- I get redirected to `google.de`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a browser/search engine ignore detecting current location](http://superuser.com/questions/410341/how-to-make-a-browser-search-engine-ignore-detecting-current-location), [Set Google Chrome search to ignore location](http://superuser.com/questions/410477/set-google-chrome-search-to-ignore-location)

Answer (score 0):

Google and other websites doesn't redirect you to other country related domains based on the locale you set on your OS. they mostly redirect you based on the IP address of you so if you're in Germany and your locale (in OS) is set to en-US, it doesn't not affect anything. in Google.com you can go to your search preferences and choose in what language you want to see your search results. alternatively you can turn off tracking and location features on your browser but that's up to websites to accept that. some websites track your location using others things like Ads and for that you can use Adblocking and anti-tracker software.