# How -exactly- do I change the default address-bar search on Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search-engines, default-settings, address-bar

Sigh. I fired up firefox today and it is somehow now set to use yahoo as the default search engine on the address bar. [This solution here](https://superuser.com/questions/253879/change-the-default-search-engine-for-firefoxs-address-bar) no longer works, because keyword.url has been removed.

I have tried googling around but I cant seem to find a solution. How can this be solved? I am using Mozilla Firefox 29.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your default search engine to Google for the search bar and Firefox's Awesome Bar will use that search engine when you type into the address bar.

[image: Google]

You can also change this from `about:config`. Find `browser.search.defaultenginename` and change it to `Google`.

Comment: Thanks Vinayak. A couple things: I do not have an awesome bar on my brower. I also tried it through config, but now when I search for something, it tries to find a site by that name... it is not taking me to google...

Comment: First of all, you **do** have [Awesome Bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs). Secondly, if you enter text with spaces in them (e.g. "cotton candy") into the address bar (aka Awesome Bar) it will take you to Google. It also works for words without spaces, so I'm not sure what you're saying here.

Comment: [Here is my mozilla screen shot](http://d.pr/i/UW9h) Where do you see a drop down from the Awesome/Address bar?

Comment: The address bar is called the Awesome Bar. What I think you were trying to find is the search bar. You can enable that by right clicking anywhere on the toolbar and selecting "Customize". Then drag and drop the search bar onto the toolbar. [This forum post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/971615#answer-480540) might be of interest to you.

Comment: No. I am not after the search bar. I want google to be the default search engine *on the address bar*. If I go to the address bar, and just start typing something, it will search google. This was what it would always do until today. Now it searches yahoo.

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment. You might want to check out [this forum post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/971615#answer-480540)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that still does not solve the problem.