# Current method to set Firefox address bar search URL?

Tags: firefox, search-engines, vimperator

I've done a bit of reading on this, but still can't figure out a nice way to do it. It might be worth mentioning that I'm using Vimperator with Firefox.

I want to set the default Firefox address-bar search URL. I will be using a DuckDuckGo URL with some of my preferences in it (so I don't have to store a cookie).

I can make a bookmarklet and assign a keyword to it, but I cannot choose this bookmarklet as a search engine (in the search engine dropdown, or in preferences dialog.)

What I want is to be able to 't %searchterm% ENTER' to make firefox search for %searchterm% in a newtab, rather than 't %KEYWORD FOR DUCKDUCKGO% %searchterm% ENTER'

Previous methods like setting Keyword.URL are depecrated, so what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The search engine that is currently set to default in Firefox's **Search bar** will also be the one used when searching in the **Address bar**.

There's an older SuperUser question about the same topic available [here](https://superuser.com/questions/253879/change-the-default-search-engine-for-firefoxs-address-bar).

Comment: The solution on that page that need to use to get the effect I want involves using Keyword.URL, which no longer works. My 'search engine' bookmarklet also doesn't show up in the search bar. The method for changing it programmatically might work for me, if I can define a URL I want to use (I'm looking for this in the article, but I don't see it.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to change the search engine for Firefox’ navigation bar or for `:open`, `:tabopen` and related commands in Vimperator / Pentadactyl? They are independent from each other; the latter is set by `'defsearch'` option.

Given `duckduckgo` as the alias for DDG (see `:dialog searchengines`), you have to:

```
:set defsearch=duckduckgo
```

Comment: I didn't know they were not the same. But if the alias isnt in my search engines dialog, how do I get to show there? I'm assuming I can't use a bookmarklet that FF isn't recognizing as a search engine..

Comment: @GrinReaper, set the alias, of course.

Comment: Ah, it accepts bookmarklets. Nice. I thought I had to much around in some Firefox *.json file for the search engine list, or go through the trouble of making a plugin or something. Thanks.